# React native open an activity

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am an Android developer who works with Android Studio most.
I started with my first react-native project for iOS and I want to know how is it possible to have one screen with a button that when the user clicks takes him to another screen (or activity in an android way) which has a hello message.
I would be really obliged to anyone that can help because I am really new to React and React-Native.

I have tried the following code but I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWUQG.png).
My code is the following:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';    
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
    import Settings from './Settings';
    import Home from './Home';

    const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    HomeScreen: { screen: Home },
    SettingScreen: { screen: Settings },
    });

    export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('./assets/adc.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.adc}>Aratos Disaster Control</Text>
        <Button title="Settings" onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingScreen')} />
      </View> 
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  adc:{
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  image:{
    width: 80,
    height: 100
  }
});


   // Home.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the home screen</Text>
        <Button title="Settings" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SettingScreen')} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Home


// Settings.js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export class Settings extends Component {


  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>This is the Settings screen</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
};

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For navigate between pages, you can use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) or [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) or other packages. You have to define the structure of your navigation and then navigate to each page using this packages. Read guides for more information.